# Closest value that results in fmod = 0

Tags: algorithm, modulo

I have two numbers at input `x`, `step`. I want `step_1` to satisfy this equation for `fmod`:

```
x - int(x / step_1) * step_1 = 0
```

`step_1` must be the closest and higher than the input `step`.

For example:

```
x = 1.0, step = 0.04
```

And I want `step_1` to be `0.0625`

Comment: Where is `step` in the equation?

Comment: isn't `step_1 = 0.05` a better solution for the example?

Answer (score 0):

This should give the correct answer. Note that there is no solution when `step > x/2`:

```
def getClosestStep(x, step):
    try:
        step_1 = x/(int(x / step)-1)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return None
    return None if step_1 < step else step_1

step_1 = getClosestStep(1, 0.04)
print(step_1) // 0.04166666666666666
```

See it run on [repl.it](https://repl.it/GsQQ/3)

Answer (score 0):

We are looking for a `step1` where `int(x / step1) = x / step1`.

We want the minimal `step1 > step`, so `x / step1 < x / step`. Therefore `int(x / step)` already fullfills that condition, unless `int(x / step) = x / step`. So we have to differentiate between two cases.

1. `if int(x / step) = x / step then return x / (x / step - 1)`.
2. `else return x / int(x / step)`.

There is no solution when `step >= x`, because then `int(x / step1)` will always return `0`.

And if `x = 0` then `step1 = step + e` where `e` is the smallest number greater than 0 for which `step + e != step`.